# How to get list of Linux capabilities

Tags: linux, posix, capabilities

I need to get a list of capabilities available to the version of linux on which the program is executed. Just in order to give user possibility to choose what capability to grant to the file. Is there any chance to do this using some standard libraries? The only way I managed to do this is to look at the bounding set of `cash --print`, but

1. Somewhy it displayes `...,cap_audit_read,38,39`, while `/usr/include/linux/capability.h` says that `CAP_LAST_CAP` is `CAP_AUDIT_READ(37)`
2. I would really use some descriptions to capabilities, if it is possible

Comment: could *man capabilities* be an appropriate starting point ?

Comment: @MC68020, I was thinking about that, but I hoped to find something more native and simple. First of all, man pages can be stored in different places depending on Linux distribution. And I'm also not confident about how to unpack an qz archive using QT (though it has to be some way).

Comment: You could do `zcat $(man -w capabilities)` to get the raw nroff source for the `man` page, wherever it may be on your system

Comment: What version of `libcap` are you using? The current version is `libcap-2.66`. Those capabilities were known to `libcap-2.37` which was released 2020-07-03.

Answer (score 0):

One or other of the following.

Command line:

```bash
$ /sbin/capsh --decode=$(grep CapBnd /proc/1/status|cut -f2)
```

In code (`list.c`):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/capability.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  for (cap_value_t c = 0; c < cap_max_bits(); c++) {
    char *name = cap_to_name(c);
    printf("%s\n", name);
    cap_free(name);
  }
}
```

Compile as follows:

```
$ gcc -o list list.c -lcap
```

Recent versions of `capsh` include the `capsh --explain=` argument. For example,

```
$ /sbin/capsh --explain=cap_chown
cap_chown (0) [/proc/self/status:CapXXX: 0x0000000000000001]

    Allows a process to arbitrarily change the user and
    group ownership of a file.
```